# Remove IOS-Android url-bar with position fixed and width and height 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-browser

[image]

Im trying to solve a problem. I have a setup, whick works perfect. Its very fluent and clean with almost native browser function(swipe, scroll etc..). My problem is, that i can't remove the url-bar in mobile-browsers, because the html and body content is not scrolling. The navigation-block and also the content-block has following the rule...

```
overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

which works very cool on IOS and Android. I know that IOS 8+ does not allow minimal-ui any more. The whole setup is for the mobile delivery of a regular webpage. I think, that 99% will not bookmark it as webapp, so that...

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

... is not helpful in this case.

Does somebody know, how i can solve this problem?

PS: The script can be downloaded here: http://www.filedropper.com/mobilenavigation